# define a tcolorbox environment with a prepending content

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox

I've successfully defined my own `tcolorbox`

```
\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[2][]{%
  blanker,
  leftupper=4cm,
  rightupper=2cm,
  after skip=1cm,
  title=\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\uppercase{#2}}},
  breakable,
  #1
}
```

but I would like to add a bigskip before the content defined by the parameter `#1`. If I redefine my environment like the following I get a compilation error:

```
\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[2][]{%
  blanker,
  leftupper=4cm,
  rightupper=2cm,
  after skip=1cm,
  title=\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\uppercase{#2}}},
  breakable,
  \bigskip #1
}
```

so I don't know how to prepend it. Is it possible? I don't want to define it each time I use `cvbox`

Comment: Bertuz, can you provide a compilable MWE? You can also mention the expected behavior in that example.

Comment: While MWE should be provided, in your first snippet, the first argument `#1` is supposed to be a valid key-value list. What do you mean by prepending `\bigskip` to a list of key-value settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your sentence `I would like to add a bigskip before the content defined by the parameter #1` is not what you want. `Parameter #1` is the optional parameter (initially empty) and will serve to add new options or change the already defined options for `cvbox`. It's not related with box contents.

In case you wanted a `\bigskip` between cvbox and previous paragraph, you should use `before=\bigskip` option (which can be introduced as optional parameter when you need it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[2][]{%
  blanker,
  leftupper=4cm,
  rightupper=2cm,
  after skip=1cm,
  title=\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\uppercase{#2}}},
  breakable,
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{cvbox}[before=\bigskip]{Example with bigskip}
\blindtext
\end{cvbox}
\newpage
\blindtext
\begin{cvbox}{Example without bigskip}
\blindtext
\end{cvbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you want the `bigskip` between cvbox title and cvboxcontents, you should use `before upper=\bigskip` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[2][]{%
  blanker,
  leftupper=4cm,
  rightupper=2cm,
  after skip=1cm,
  title=\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\uppercase{#2}}},
  breakable,
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{cvbox}[before upper=\bigskip]{Example with bigskip}
\blindtext
\end{cvbox}
\newpage
\blindtext
\begin{cvbox}{Example without bigskip}
\blindtext
\end{cvbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]